# SQL Server 2016 SSIS Conditionally Overwrite Text File

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016

Image the following scenario:
1. there are N number of jobs
2. the jobs write data to the same file once a day sequentially
3. task setting indicates whether the file should be overwritten or appended to

what i've tried thus far is using a `conditional split` in my `data flow`:

[image: conditional split]

to test it out, the Case 1 & 2 are:

[image]

what actually happens is, conditional split tries to work out which data rows to send where, ends up sending all rows to one side and 0 rows to the other and both sides end up opening the file (i think), hence the errors:

[image]

i get that i'm misusing the `conditional split` here, but come one, it's 2017 outside, the **must** be a way to do this without resorting to *Script tasks* clearing the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem - you are misusing *Conditional Split*; it is designed to manipulate data rows in a data flow and you are trying to manage control flow. Speaking of SSIS, it does not know in advance that you will use only one of *Flat File Destinations*; it tries to initialize both. By doing so SSIS tries to open the same file from two Destinations and fails with an error.
You can handle the task the SSIS way - manage control flow with tasks. In your case, the destination file should be appended or being overwritten. But the being overwritten can be viewed as being overwritten with zero lines and then being appended. Luckily for you, SSIS overwrites a file event no records are coming from a Data Flow.
So, before your dataflow which should always append data, you create another dataflow which always receives ZERO lines of data (columns in the set can be arbitrary) and *Flat File Destination* overwriting the file. Then use conditional execution of control flow with precedence constrains to execute this "File Cleanup DataFlow Task". You might also need to set `DelayValidation=true` on this "File Cleanup DataFlow Task".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've moved the logic into the Control Flow with a parameterised "Delete File" task.